# Office 365 iOS SDK - How to invoke SharePoint REST API

Tags: ios, swift, sharepoint, office365, adal

All the iOS SDK samples provide working code for accessing Mail, Calendar, ODfB FIles, but none show how to access SharePoint list items. So I am trying a simple REST call in Swift, but keep getting the following error:

[0] (null)  @"error_description" : @"Unsupported security token.

Here is a subset of my code when my App starts:

```
var resourceID : String = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com"
var authorityURL : String = "https://login.windows.net/common/"
var clientID : String = "xxd4200eb-7284-41be-a434-abb269b82f0f"
var redirectURI : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.mycompanywebsite.com")!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var er : ADAuthenticationError? = nil
    var authContext:ADAuthenticationContext = ADAuthenticationContext(authority: authorityURL, error: &er)

    authContext.acquireTokenWithResource(resourceID, clientId: clientID, redirectUri: redirectURI) { (result: ADAuthenticationResult!) -> Void in
        if (result.accessToken == nil) {
            println("token nil")
        } else {
            defaults.setObject(result.accessToken, forKey: "accessTokenDefault")
            defaults.synchronize()
            println("accessToken: \(result.accessToken)")
        }
    }
}
```

Then, once I get the Token, I invoke the following code that tries an http GET but fails:

```
    var resolver : MSODataDefaultDependencyResolver = MSODataDefaultDependencyResolver()

    var credentials : MSODataOAuthCredentials = MSODataOAuthCredentials()
    var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    credentials.addToken(defaults.objectForKey("accessTokenDefault") as! String)
    var credentialsImpl : MSODataCredentialsImpl = MSODataCredentialsImpl()
    credentialsImpl.setCredentials(credentials)
    resolver.setCredentialsFactory(credentialsImpl)

    //build API string to get a sample list info
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://umaknow.sharepoint.com/_api/web?$select=Title")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    let token = defaults.stringForKey("accessTokenDefault")
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json; odata=verbose", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")

    //make the call to the SharePoint REST API
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error:NSError? = nil
        let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if (jsonResult != nil) {
            //parse the json into File objects in the table view
            let results:NSArray = (jsonResult["d"] as! NSDictionary)["results"] as! NSArray
```

And this is where it fails with the error message. Monitoring the web traffic, the following is a bit more details about what is going on:

This is my request (RAW):

```
GET /_api/web?$select=Title HTTP/1.1
Host: mytenant.sharepoint.com
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json; odata=verbose
User-Agent: O365Demo/1 CFNetwork/711.3.18 Darwin/14.3.0
Accept-Language: en-us
Authorization: Bearer Optional("eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLDJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSIsImtpZCI6Ik1uQ19WWmNBVGZNNXBPWWlKSE1iYTlnb0VLWSJ9.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.aAkaEIFuOeiI0ZRydzaOBTl5wyqLDYBHfvbSj6nZAk4jQKBZF6BhJsAAnhu9qj8oMR2gUdVr3vCNgzefvlZxcf3u0k6R8g4176M-bU3rAABri9DjyaZJ24jMs1u-kL0h5Ee8mvNXSI7BF7Qv9JoeHIiXLei_SXba1s8mhdwMaw9Se9tl8MbBFPLDDBLXUa4YgC_rYWO7G7rw3JEe3GmEV9NffZ7zklXxd55P8fxtbz0-KhI0wbRHIXN69wAuC0jiqhJ4FCCGzLvTuuUbirhURrhi4UizYpLWqqnr0I8zWAMvr8WUXCWtZhPkzOZ5teqbvBwp1UwYui42O6S0PfYKzQ")
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

And finally the RAW response from the site

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
x-ms-diagnostics: 3000006;reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"
SPRequestGuid: 84c9139d-807c-2000-0e59-4caf75bd097f
request-id: 84c9139d-807c-2000-0e59-4caf75bd097f
SPRequestDuration: 19
SPIisLatency: 1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4107
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="56fc9778-8aac-45d2-9305-b9171ffafa8c",client_id="00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,https://sts.windows.net/*/,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@90140122-8516-11e1-8eff-49304924019b",authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize"
Date: Thu, 25 Jun 2015 11:12:40 GMT
Content-Length: 51

{"error_description":"Unsupported security token."}
```

So there is something obviously wrong with the way I use the Token provided, but with my very limited OAuth2 knowledge and the lack of samples, I am at a lost.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone gets the same issue, I finally found what was wrong. It has nothing to do with ADAL or SharePoint REST, but a syntactic error in Swift. The line that read:

```
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

generates the following in the HTTP request:

```
Authorization: Bearer Optional("eyJ0eXAiOi....
```

The "Optional("...") has something to do with the insertion of the token variable in the string. By just replacing the statement with:

```
request.setValue("Bearer " + token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

now generates the correct header in the HTTP request:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOi...
```

and I get the data I want back from the call.

So this is really a newbie Swift programmer error! :-)

Comment: HI can you please post a sample app that access SharePoint? I am looking everywhere and I only found depreciated examples that no more works.